# How to count Proffessor Students Per Courses

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is to show the students of a specific faculty. Now for you to understand more please read the statement below:

I have created first a looping statement for all courses. Then, every loop, I have insert also another looping statement for the subjects to display the subjects per course of a specific faculty and group by course. Then I put also another looping statements to show the students per courses. I have successfully displayed the students but the problem is I can't count all students. Anyone? Please help me. Here's my codes by the way.

```
/* Get the Total Students */
$get_courses = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses");
$get_courses->execute();

while ($course = $get_courses->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $get_subjs = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE course = :course AND f_id = :f_id GROUP BY COURSE");
    $get_subjs->bindparam(":course", $course["course_acronym"]);
    $get_subjs->bindparam(':f_id', $my_fac_id);
    $get_subjs->execute();

    while ($subjects = $get_subjs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $get_stds = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE course = :course");
        $get_stds->bindparam(":course", $course['course_acronym']);

        $get_stds->execute();

        while ($stds = $get_stds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            echo $stds["firstname"] . ' ' . $stds["lastname"] . "<br/>";

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Within the students per courses loop, you could assign the current student to an array variable and get the total students by counting it :

```
/* Get the Total Students */
$get_courses = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses");
$get_courses->execute();

while ($course = $get_courses->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $get_subjs = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE course = :course AND f_id = :f_id GROUP BY COURSE");
    $get_subjs->bindparam(":course", $course["course_acronym"]);
    $get_subjs->bindparam(':f_id', $my_fac_id);
    $get_subjs->execute();

    while ($subjects = $get_subjs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $get_stds = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE course = :course");
        $get_stds->bindparam(":course", $course['course_acronym']);

        $get_stds->execute();

        while ($stds = $get_stds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            echo $stds["firstname"] . ' ' . $stds["lastname"] . "<br/>";
            $students[$stds["firstname"] . $stds["lastname"]] = '1';

        }

    }

}

$total_students = isset($students) ? count($students) : '0';
```